# grunt-contrib-requirejs knockout component issue

Tags: knockout.js, gruntjs, requirejs

When using [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) to build my project, my [knockout components'](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#an-amd-module-whose-value-describes-a-template) modules, which are only referenced in the component itself (`text` and `mapping`) won't get added to my compressed output script file.

**my knockout module:**

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./foo.html', 'mapping'], ....)
```

Since the component is injected asynchronously at run time - AFAIK - 
grunt-contrib-requirejs doesn't pick them up and add them to my compressed file, `out: "<%= settings.getBuildPath() %>/js/lib/require/require.js",` below:

**grunt config:**

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: 'src/js',
            mainConfigFile: "src/js/app.js",
            name: 'app',
            out: "<%= settings.getBuildPath() %>/js/optimized.js",
            preserveLicenseComments: false,
            include: ['lib/require/require.js']
        }
    }       
}
```

If I reference them in another of my script files which are not a knockout component module, the project builds fine.

So, how can I make grunt-contrib-requirejs add scripts which are referenced in my components as well?

Comment: Please explain why You overwrite requirejs with Your compressed file? I guess `<%= settings.getBuildPath() %>/js/lib/require/require.js` and `lib/require/require.js` is the same file.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup No they aren't. My index.html has one script reference: `<script data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require/require.js"></script>`. So when all files gets compressed in to one file, it needs to have the same name. The actual require.js is included with `include: ['lib/require/require.js']`, since the optimizer removes it. Even though this is not my problem at the moment, do you have any concerns about this method? If I would call it something like `out.js`, I would need to modify the script tag accordingly in grunt, right?

Comment: `out: 'out.js'` and load it `<script src="out.js"></script>`. Show full working example on GitHub or BitBucket

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup Sure, but that's just about moving and renaming files. Regardless of its location and name, I will have the very same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to this problem is to use a module for registering components and require the templates and viewmodels here to ensure r.js will include them in the bundle.

I usually require and call this module in main.js.

```
// registerComponents.js
define(
['knockout', 'componentViewModel', 'text!componentTemplate.html', ],
function (ko, componentViewModel, componentTemplate) {

    return function () {
        ko.components.register('myComponent', {
            viewModel: componentViewModel,
            template: componentTemplate
        });
    };

});

// main.js
require(['registerComponents'], function (registerComponents) {
    registerComponents();
});
```

Comment: Good idea. My current solution is to use the `include` setting and include the components there. I'll give this a thought :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your application, maybe you would like to place all your HTML to single JS file and use custom Knockout component loader.

```
grunt.registerTask("generate-templates", function () {
    var componentTemplates = grunt.file.expand('components/**/*.html');
    var incldesContent = '';
    var imports = componentTemplates.map(function (item) {

        var content = fs.readFileSync(item, { encoding: 'utf8' }).toString();
        content = content.trim().replace(/["'\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]/g, function (character) {
            // Escape all characters not included in SingleStringCharacters and
            // DoubleStringCharacters on
            // http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4
            switch (character) {
                case '"':
                case "'":
                case '\\':
                    return '\\' + character
                    // Four possible LineTerminator characters need to be escaped:
                case '\n':
                    return '\\n'
                case '\r':
                    return '\\r'
                case '\u2028':
                    return '\\u2028'
                case '\u2029':
                    return '\\u2029'
            }
        })
        return "templatesCache['" + item + "'] = '" + content + "';";
    });
    grunt.file.write('wwwroot/templates.js', '// This file is autogenerated. DO NOT EDIT.\nvar templatesCache=[];\n' + imports.join('\n'));
});
```

and below the code for registration of the template. It is in TypeScript, but should be easiely translated to JS.

```
declare var templatesCache: any[];
enter code here
/**
* Dynamically register component based on component naming conventions
*/
function registerComponent(componentName: string, folderName: string, componentData?: string) {
    componentData = componentData || componentName;
    var componentTemplate: string | KnockoutComponentTypes.AMDModule;
    if (window["templatesCache"]) {
        componentTemplate = templatesCache["components/" + folderName + "/" + componentData + "/" + componentData + ".html"];
    } else {
        componentTemplate = { require: "text!components/" + folderName + "/" + componentData + "/" + componentData + ".html" }
    }
    ko.components.register(componentName, {
        template: componentTemplate,
        viewModel: { require: "components/" + folderName + "/" + componentData + "/" + componentData + "" }
   });
}

/* Shared components */
registerComponent("tabbar", "shared");
registerComponent("left-bar", "shared");
registerComponent("photo-loader", "shared");
```

Essentially, my grunt task prepare `templates.js` which declare `templateCache` variable which is used by the component loader, but it is require that I manually register KO components. You could avoid that, by following naming conventions and generation of registration file from your folder structure. My app was relatively simple, so I end-up with manual registration and don't do that extra step.